# How can we NOT display certain rows in a flask-admin view?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have been searching and trying for a while but could not find any answer so any help is appreciated.
I have a flask admin-view, say the following:

```
class testViewMain():
    column_list = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone',
    ]
```

How can I exclude certain values on this flask view? 
For example, display only rows from the database where `first_name != John and last_name != Doe`.

I thought the function I was looking for is `on_form_prefill`, but according to the documentation, this is only on the edit view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
class testViewMain():
    column_list = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone',
    ]

    def get_query(self):
       return self.session.query(self.model).filter(
                       self.model.first_name != 'John' \
                   and self.model.last_name != 'Doe')
```